# Pass an element from C type string array to a COM object as BSTR? (in C++)

Tags: c++, c, com, bstr

I am writing a C++ DLL that is called by an external program.

1.) I take an array of strings (as char *var) as an argument from this program.

2.) I want to iterate through this array and call a COM function on each element of the string array. The COM function must take a BSTR:

```
DLL_EXPORT(void) runUnitModel(char *rateMaterialTypeNames) {

    HRESULT hr = CoInitialize(NULL);

    // Create the interface pointer.
    IUnitModelPtr pIUnit(__uuidof(BlastFurnaceUnitModel));

    pIUnit->initialiseUnitModel();

    int i;
    for(i=0; i < sizeOfPortRatesArray; i++)
            pIUnit->createPort(SysAllocString(BSTR((const char *)rateMaterialTypeNames[i])));
```

I think its the SysAllocString(BSTR((const char *)rateMaterialTypeNames[i])) bit that is giving me problems. I get an access violation when the programs runs.

Is this the right way to access the value of the rateMaterialTypeName at i? Note I am expecting something like "IronOre" as the value at i, not a single character.

Comment: Thanks guys, CComBSTR did the trick. Thanks for finding the double pointer bug Mathew!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you're using Microsofts **ATL**, you can use the [CComBSTR](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zh7x9w3f(VS.80).aspx) class.
It will accept a char* and create a BSTR from it, also, you don't need to worry about deleting the BSTR, all that happens in the dtor for CComBSTR.

Also, see [Matthew Xaviers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/586734/pass-an-element-from-c-type-string-array-to-a-com-object-as-bstr-in-c/586787#586787) answer, it doesn't look like you're passing your array of strings into that function properly.

Hope this helps

Answer (score 4):

Because a variable holding a C string is just a pointer to the first element (a char*), in order to pass an array of C strings, the parameter to your function should be a char**:

```
DLL_EXPORT(void) runUnitModel(char **rateMaterialTypeNames)
```

This way, when you evaluate rateMaterialTypeNames[i], the result will be a char*, which is the parameter type you need to pass to SysAllocString().

Added note: you will also need to convert the strings to wide chars at some point, as Tommy Hui's answer points out.

Comment: +1 for spotting the problem with the parameter. See my answer for an easy - but ATL specific - way to create the BStr

Answer (score 3):

If the parameter to the function rateMaterialTypeNames is a string, then

rateMaterialTypeNames[i]

is a character and not a string. You should use just the parameter name itself.

In addition, casts in general are bad. The conversion to a BSTR is a big flag. The parameter type for SysAllocString is

const OLECHAR*

which for 32-bit compilers is a wide character. So this will definitely fail because the actual parameter is a char*.

What the code needs is a conversion of narrow string to a wide string.

```
const OLECHAR* pOleChar = A2COLE( *pChar );
BSTR str = SysAllocString( pOleChar );
// do something with the 'str'
SysFreeString( str ); // need to cleanup the allocated BSTR
```